# Issue in Updating CreationDate and ModificationDate fields of PDF metadata using Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, metadata

I tried running a simple matplotlib code for plotting an image and saving it in .pdf output.I want few PDF metadata fields to be created along with the file creation.When I tried running the below code ,I found CreationDate and ModifiedDate metadata fields alone missing.The code is not throwing error but it is not Updating the respective field.

How to Update the CreationDate and ModifiedDate fields in PDF metadata using matplotlib?

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(7), [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2], 'r-o')
plt.title('Test_Graph')
dict_inp = {'Author':'Coder','Title':'Test','CreationDate':datetime.datetime.now() ,'ModDate':datetime.datetime.now()}
plt.savefig(('single_image_pdf'+'.pdf'),metadata = dict_inp)  # saves the current figure into a pdf page
plt.close()
```

## My_output:

[PDF_METADATA_OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEQ32.png)

Comment: hi, i didn't find any error on the code, neither on the saved file metadata. Try to inspect the metadata of the file in another way.

Comment: Hi Guilherme ,Can you able to see the created date and modified date in the saved file after running this code?IF yes ,which tool you have used for inspecting the pdf metadata.( I used Adobe Reader)

Comment: i just right-clicked the file, and took a look at  the properties

Comment: Hi Guilherme,That was created by OS itself.I am trying to replicate that inside my created file by trying to display the Creation date and modification date inside the tool(eg:Adobe Reader) properties which my code should have to achieve it.

Comment: nop, i put some custom data to test it